# Why isn't my html file suddenly not working?

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to work on a html file. But I'm getting this error. I'm working on windows xp. I don't know what the error means. I tried running the files on my laptop running on windows 10 and it's giving the same error. I'm attaching a screenshot.[image]

Comment: postimage.org revoked access to these image. End of the quest.

Comment: the images are visible, just not allowed in your webpage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adam Axad said, the `postimage.org` denying access to the images, since its a 403 error.

Make sure whether the `postimage.org` has o+x (public enter) permission and image has o+r (public read) permission.

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

The 403 Forbidden error is an HTTP status code which means that accessing the page or resource you were trying to reach is absolutely forbidden for some reason.

Just replace the images to you local once or which you have access to and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

Adam and Thinker answered it, but 403 means you don't have permission to access that url. As the other two said, just try putting the images elsewhere and then linking to them at their new destination.

For future reference, here is a list of all the HTTP response codes. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status

These make it easier to troubleshoot various issues like the one you're facing here, and they are good to know anyways!